# How to create a generic MVC3 editor template?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, templates

I'm using the following code-snippet extensively in my model templates.

```
<div class="control-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
    <div class="controls">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "span3" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to encapsulate this generically in *an editor template* so I can use Html.EditorFor(...) **without** resorting to a custom extension?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it possible to encapsulate this generically in an editor template
>   so I can use Html.EditorFor(...) without resorting to a custom
>   extension?

Of course:

`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Foo.cshtml`:

```
<div class="control-group">
    @Html.Label("")
    <div class="controls">
        @Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, new { @class = "span3" })
        @Html.ValidationMessage("")
    </div>
</div>
```

and then:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.FirstName, "Foo")
```

or:

```
[UIHint("Foo")]
pubilc string FirstName { get; set; }
```

and then:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.FirstName)
```

Comment: You probably don't need the `"Foo"` on the last example. I had no idea you can use `("")` like that...  Also, congratulations on *almost* reaching 300k.

Comment: @Kobi, yes, I have just realized and fixed that.

Comment: Also if you use control-group syntax in many partial views you can abstract it away to a single method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083147/how-to-abstract-common-snippets-of-markup-with-asp-net-mvc/14455144#14455144

Comment: I would add:


    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]

also for MV6 I would use:

http://blog.emikek.com/reinstating-imetadataaware-in-asp-net-5-vnext-mvc-6/