# How to change the width of editorfor in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-editor-templates, editorfor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a generic MVC3 editor template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885198/how-to-create-a-generic-mvc3-editor-template)

I am using editorfor as my input control and this is going out of my form when the screen resolution is low. I need to reduce the width of the control to fix this problem. I am trying to write an editor template for this but i am not figure out how. Please help me here.

Comment: I have the below code for a texbox control but i am not able to write for editorfor control
@Html.TextBox("", string.Format("{0:0.00}", Model), (@Model.GetValueOrDefault() < 0) ? new { style = "color:red; width:150px;" } : new { style = "color:#000000; width:150px;" })

Comment: Are you asking how to [create custom EditorFor templates](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html), or how to style the inputs with CSS?

Comment: I need to create custom editorfor template. The width of the editor for control has to be reduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119221/how-can-i-change-the-size-of-a-multi-line-editor-field).  They seemed to be able to manipulate the EditorFor field by wrapping it in a div and then using CSS to manipulate the div.