# Convert a boolean property editor to a dropdownlist in MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I currently have scaffolded a view where a boolean property of my model gets passed to the Html.EditorFor helper:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndCurrentDeal)
```

All well and good, but what I'm really looking to do is massage that into a dropdown like:

```
<select>
    <option value="true" selected="selected">Yes</option>
    <option value="false">No</option>
</select>
```

What's the easiest way to achieve that?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: see this response http://stackoverflow.com/a/9885229/138071

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can try something like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517627/converting-html-editorfor-into-a-drop-down-html-dropdownfor):

```
<%= Html.DropDownList(
    "", 
    new SelectList(
        new[] 
        { 
            new { Value = "true", Text = "Yes" },
            new { Value = "false", Text = "No" },
        }, 
        "Value", 
        "Text",
        Model
    )
) %>
```

If you want a default Value :

```
<%= Html.DropDownList(
        "", 
        new SelectList(
            new[] 
            { 
                new { Value = "", Text = "None" },
                new { Value = "true", Text = "Yes" },
                new { Value = "false", Text = "No" },
            }, 
            "Value", 
            "Text",
            Model
        )
    ) %>
```

Comment: What if the `bool` value is nullable? How to create a null option?

Comment: I see the update thank you. Can I also do `value = "null"`?

Answer (score 24):

MVC 4

```
@*/////////////////// bool ////////////////////////////////*@
@model bool

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, new SelectList(
        new[] 
        { 
            new { Value = "true", Text = "Yes" },
            new { Value = "false", Text = "No" },
        },
        "Value",
        "Text",
        Model
    ))

@*/////////////////// bool? ////////////////////////////////*@    
@model bool?

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, new SelectList(
        new[] 
        { 
            new { Value = "", Text = "(none)" },
            new { Value = "true", Text = "Yes" },
            new { Value = "false", Text = "No" },
        },
        "Value",
        "Text",
        Model
    ))
```

Answer (score 10):

You can also try Dictionary approach is a bit cleaner and can be easily added to your constructor for View Model.

ViewModel

```
 //Define IDictionary interface
 public IDictionary<bool, string> options { get; set; }

public YourViewModel()
{
  // Default constructor
        this.options = new Dictionary<bool, string>();
        this.options.Add(false, "no");
        this.options.Add(true, "yes");
}




@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.yourPropertyToEdit, new SelectList( Model.options, "Key", "Value"))
```

Answer (score 5):

I got inspired with the very useful answer from Francois Borgies, so I decided to write a custom method that creates **SelectList** for **Boolean** value that can be used in  **@Html.DropDownList**.  When you have a helper method that can be used in every view, then it reduces the amount of code needed in razor views.

My project has **CustomHelpers.cs** class in folder: *App_Code/Helpers*

```
namespace YourProjectName.App_Code.Helpers
{
    public static class CustomHelpers
    {
        public static SelectList SelectListForBoolean(object selectedValue = null)
        {
            SelectListItem[] selectListItems = new SelectListItem[2];

            var itemTrue = new SelectListItem();
            itemTrue.Value = "true";
            itemTrue.Text = "Yes";
            selectListItems[0] = itemTrue;

            var itemFalse = new SelectListItem();
            itemFalse.Value = "false";
            itemFalse.Text = "No";
            selectListItems[1] = itemFalse;

            var selectList = new SelectList(selectListItems, "Value","Text", selectedValue);

            return selectList;
        }           
    }
}
```

In the *create* view you can use it as follows:

```
@model Foo
@using YourProjectName.App_Code.Helpers;
...
@Html.DropDownList("EndCurrentDeal", CustomHelpers.SelectListForBoolean(), "-select-")
```

for *edit* view

```
@model Bar
@using YourProjectName.App_Code.Helpers;
...
@Html.DropDownList("EndCurrentDeal", CustomHelpers.SelectListForBoolean(Model.EndCurrentDeal), "-select-")
```

Although my helper method is not pure HTML Helper because it creates **SelectList**, - it nevertheless follows same functionality that was presented by Rahul Rajat Singh, in his excellent article [An Absolute Beginner's Tutorial on HTML Helpers and Creating Custom HTML Helpers in ASP.NET MVC](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/787320/an-absolute-beginners-tutorial-on-html-helpers-and)